# JWT with permissions

Tags: authentication, security, jwt

JWT permissions

We have an api where Organisations can create Events. Every member of an Organisation can attend/view all Organisation events. So every Organisation the user is a member of gets added to the jwt claims so we can easily check if a user has these attend/view permissions

Events can also be joined by users outside of the organisaiton using an invite link. These users will not necessarily be added to the Organisation.

Right now we only add the Organisation ID to the JWT and check in the auth middleware whether the user is a member of the Event’s Organisation.

And when the user is not a member of the Organisation and tries to attend/view an Event we do a db lookup.

This becomes db heavy when an Event is attended by 100s/1000s of users outside the Organisation.

A solution we want to implement is to put all upcoming Event ID which the user will attend in the JWT and fall back to the db lookup when for example they view an event in the past.

Is this a good solution? Are there other solutions?

Thanks

Comment: "This becomes db heavy when an Event is attended by 100s/1000s of users outside the Organisation." - thousands should not be "heavy" for a database, even one on very basic hardware.

Comment: Reducing api calls must at least make the api call faster. But do you thinks this is a good way to handle the authorization and simulaniously reduce db calls?